# Traversing a json abstract syntax tree to build boolean expression

Tags: javascript, json, tree, boolean

After doing hours of research on google and stack overflow, I've come to the conclusion that the following JSON structure properly describes a boolean expression.  I'm not terribly keen on algorithms, but in english (and/or javascript), how would you recursively traverse the tree to rebuild the expression so, in this example, the expression would read:

13 or 14 or (18 and 20 and 19)

```
var booleanExpression = {
    op   : 'or',
    left : {
        op  : 'or',
        left: {
            op   : 'or',
            left : {
                op   : 'literal',
                value: '14'
            },
            right: {
                op   : 'and',
                left : {
                    op   : 'and',
                    left : {
                        op   : 'literal',
                        value: '20'
                    },
                    right: {
                        op   : 'literal',
                        value: '19'
                    }
                },
                right: {
                    op   : 'literal',
                    value: '18'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    right: {
        op   : 'literal',
        value: '13'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

[Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) is your friend for evaluating an expression tree. All you need to do is handle the individual op types and defer to a recursive evaluation of their children. Generally the hard part of parsing/evaluating things is getting it into a tree-based structure. After that it's pretty easy to recursively walk the tree:

```
function eval_expr(expr) {
  if( !expr ) { return false; }
  var op = expr.op;
  if( op == 'literal' ) {
    return expr.value;
  } else if( op == 'or' ) {
    return "(" + eval_expr(expr.left) + ") or (" + eval_expr(expr.right) + ")";
  } else if( op == 'and' ) {
    return "(" + eval_expr(expr.left) + ") and (" + eval_expr(expr.right) + ")";
  }
  console.error("Unhandled op:" + expr.op);
}


> eval_expr(booleanExpression);
"(((14) or (((20) and (19)) and (18))) or (false)) or (13)"
```

Note that this function treats non-zero 'literal' type values as true and zero values as false.

Comment: I'm not attempting to evaluate the tree, I'm just trying to rebuild the tree-structure into a string.

Comment: @ThinkingInBits The code will look the same - just that the result of evaluation will be to concatenate, rather than to come up with the numerical result, for example `return eval_expr(expr.left) + " OR " + eval_expr(expr.right);` (and handle brackets, etc)

Comment: You need to include the parenthesis as well. As otherwise the operator precedence would not be correct once it's "stringified".

Comment: sehrope: how would you include the parenthesis here?

Comment: Is there some way to not include the or (false)) for the root node?